# Adding timeout to avformat_open_input

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am trying to add timeout to the function avformat_open_input using dictionary options.

here is my code.

```
AVDictionary *dict = NULL; // "create" an empty dictionary
av_dict_set(&dict, "timeout", "6000", 0); // add an entry           
if (avformat_open_input(&av_format_ctx, "rtmp://192.168.1.2:1935/live/sum", NULL, &dict) < 0) {
    return false;
}
```

but the function does not wait for 6 seconds it exits immediately after being called.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is an old question, but anyhow...
The timeout option is used in listen mode.
According to the ffmpeg documentation:

> timeout Set maximum timeout (in seconds) to wait for incoming connections.
> A value of -1 means infinite (default). This option implies the rtsp_flags set to listen.

Check the console after the error when trying to set the timeout option. I bet it is saying that it could not open the rtsp for listening.
Use stimeout:

> stimeout Set socket TCP I/O timeout in microseconds.

Pay double attention on the number of zeros (microseconds)